# Acumatica Currency Rate Behavior

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to copy the `Currency Behavior` of `APInvoiceEntry BLC`.

I'm confused, I copied already all the events, but with no luck, 
`CurrencyInfo_RowUpdated` does not fire event. I am certain that this event is the `Currency Conversion` when you Click `View Cury` or `View Base`.

Somehow I managed to save `CuryInfoID` information on the Database. I'm only getting confused on the client events.

Am I missing something? I copied also the `Currency Rate` and set it to my own `Currency Rate view`. so it is working. Please enlighten me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **View Base/View Cury** action is handled by the `ToggleCurrency.Handler()` method. The APInvoiceEntry graph has the `ToggleCurrency<APInvoice> CurrencyView;` member which drives the button. Here is an example on how you could override it in an APInvoiceEntry graph extension:

```cs
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CM;

namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
    public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
    {
        public CustomToggleCurrency<APInvoice> CurrencyView;
    }

    public class CustomToggleCurrency<TNode> : ToggleCurrency<TNode>
        where TNode : class, IBqlTable, new()
    {
        public CustomToggleCurrency(PXGraph graph, string name)
            : base(graph, name)
        {
        }

        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Toggle Currency", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        [PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.Money, Tooltip = PX.Objects.CM.Messages.ToggleCurrencyViewTooltip)]
        protected override System.Collections.IEnumerable Handler(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            return base.Handler(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this.

Comment: Getting back, this works for me, just need a little tweak on my own implementation :) Thanks!!